# I am trying to use nested loops to give the player the option of going to the pokemart or tall grass

Tags: python, if-statement

When i give the option it is automatically going to pokemart instead of tall grass.

```
place_1 = input("Where do you want to go?")
if place_1 == "pokemart":
  print("You go to the pokemart")
  print("Seller: Hello! Welcome to the pokemart!")
  print("Seller:  Hi! I work at a POKEMON MART. It's a convenient shop, so please visit us in VIRIDIAN CITY. I know, I'll give you a sample! Here you go!")
  print("You get 3 potions and 3 pokeballs")
  print("Customer: See those ledges along the road? It's a bit scary, but you can jump from them. You can get back to PALLET TOWN quicker that way.")
pokemart_1 = input("Would you like to buy a potion or a pokeball?")
if pokemart_1 == "potion":
  print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a potion")
  money = money - 100
  print(money)
elif pokemart_1 == "pokeball":
  print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a pokeball")
  money = money - 100
  print(money)
else:
  print("You go to the tall grass")
```

i expected to have the option.

Comment: Indentation matters. `pokemart_1` and all checks related to it must be intended within `if place_1 == "pokemart":` to make sense and cause the `else` to "go to tall grass". Otherwise, you are always asking to buy something, or go to the tall grass, regardless of the first prompt

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off. Because the second part was not indented within the first conditional block, it ran regardless of the value of `place_1`.

```
place_1 = input("Where do you want to go?")
if place_1 == "pokemart":
    print("You go to the pokemart")
    print("Seller: Hello! Welcome to the pokemart!")
    print("Seller:  Hi! I work at a POKEMON MART. It's a convenient shop, so please visit us in VIRIDIAN CITY. I know, I'll give you a sample! Here you go!")
    print("You get 3 potions and 3 pokeballs")
    print("Customer: See those ledges along the road? It's a bit scary, but you can jump from them. You can get back to PALLET TOWN quicker that way.")
    pokemart_1 = input("Would you like to buy a potion or a pokeball?")
    if pokemart_1 == "potion":
        print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a potion")
        money = money - 100
        print(money)
    elif pokemart_1 == "pokeball":
        print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a pokeball")
        money = money - 100
        print(money)
else:
    print("You go to the tall grass")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out which statements should be indented.

Answer (score -1):

all the code should be inside the first if statement except the else statement at the end

```
place_1 = input("Where do you want to go?")
if place_1 == "pokemart":
  print("You go to the pokemart")
  print("Seller: Hello! Welcome to the pokemart!")
  print("Seller:  Hi! I work at a POKEMON MART. It's a convenient shop, so please 
  visit us in VIRIDIAN CITY. I know, I'll give you a sample! Here you go!")
  print("You get 3 potions and 3 pokeballs")
  print("Customer: See those ledges along the road? It's a bit scary, but you can 
  jump from them. You can get back to PALLET TOWN quicker that way.")
  pokemart_1 = input("Would you like to buy a potion or a pokeball?")
  if pokemart_1 == "potion":
  print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a potion")
  money = money - 100
  print(money)
  elif pokemart_1 == "pokeball":
  print("You spend 100 pokedollars on a pokeball")
  money = money - 100
  print(money)
else:
  print("You go to the tall grass")
```

Comment: This is not correct. There's no identation in the nested conditional.